# Applying existential instantation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

After breaking down the problem and applying existential instantation on this statement $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_i - \cap_{i \in I} B_i)$. Should I let, $i' \in I \land x \in A_{i'}$, and $i'' \in I \land x \notin B_{i''}$ which means I assigned 2 different variables since I used existential instantation twice. I am using Velleman's How to Prove It book, if that helps in clarifying my question.

Add'l Background:Originally the problem asks me to prove $\cup_{i \in I} A_i - B_i \subset ((\cup_{i \in I} A_i - \cap_{i \in I} B_i))$. I kinda did that. Next problem was to give some sets that would prove that they are not equivalent but since the former is a subset of the latter then I reasoned that what makes it not equivalent must be because the latter is not the subset of the former. So I tried to analyse $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_i - \cap_{i \in I} B_i)$. What i got was this: $\exists i \in I (x \in A_i) \land \exists i \in I (x \notin B_i)$.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to prove or do.  State clearly the theorem, and then explain what you've done so far.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to apply existential instantiation *twice* to this statement?  For any $x$ in the composite set there is *no guarantee* that it is in *more than one* of the sets in $(A_i)_{i\in I}$.

Comment: To say that $x \in (\cup A_i \setminus \cap B_j)$ (note that the indexes $i$ and $j$ are "independent") means that $x$ belongs to the set $\cup A_i$ and **not** belongs to the set $\cap B_j$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $(x\notin \bigcap_j B_j) \iff (\exists j: x\notin B_j)$ since the complement of an intersection is a union of complements; vis de Morgan's Law.

Comment: So, **there is** an $i_0$ such that $x ∈ A_{i_0}$ and **there is** a $j_0$ such that $x \notin B_{j_0}$. $i_0$ and $j_0$ are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Prove $\bigcup_{i \in I} \big(A_i\smallsetminus B_i\big)\subseteq \Big(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \smallsetminus  \bigcap_{i \in I} B_i\Big)$

Well $\quad\bigcup_{i\in I} \big(A_i\smallsetminus B_i\big) ~=~ \{x\mid \exists i\in I~(x\in A_i\wedge x\notin B_i)\}$

And $\quad\Big(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \smallsetminus  \bigcap_{i \in I} B_i\Big) ~=~ \{x\mid \exists i\in I~(x\in A_i)~\wedge~\neg\forall i\in I~(x\in B_i)\} $

You have stated that you have a proof for: $$\forall x~\Big(\exists i\in I~(x\in A_i\wedge x\notin B_i)~\to~\big(\exists i\in I~(x\in A_i)~\wedge~\exists j\in I~(x\notin B_j)\big)\Big)$$

(And yes, clearly so.)

So that leaves you needing to demonstrate that the contrapositive may *possibly be false*.

Just construct a counterexample:

$$(\{1,2\}\smallsetminus\{1\})\cup(\{3\}\smallsetminus\{2,3\})=\{2\}$$
$$(\{1,2\}\cup\{3\})\smallsetminus(\{1\}\cap\{2,3\})=\{1,2,3\}$$

Comment: I guess this part of your answer is what I am look (∃i∈I (x∈Ai) ∧ ∃j∈I (x∉Bj))). j and i not being the same. This symbol confused me (⋃i∈IAi∖⋂i∈IBi) because they share the "i" that is why I asked if it existential instantation is applied twice. I couldnt properly express my thought on the question.

Comment: I see.  Yes, although the same token may be used, variables bound into different scopes are not the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

The existential instantiation seems odd. You might need to have $i'=i''$ since it's not guaranteed that more than one of $A_i$ contains $i$.

The proof for the first problem goes something like you assume that $x\in \bigcup(A_i-B_i)$ which means there's an $i$ such that $x\in A_i-B_i$ that is $x\in A_i$ but $x\notin B_i$. Then obviously $x\in \bigcup A_i$ and $x\notin \bigcap B_i$.

The way to produce counter-examples are often hinted by the proof. You have here that you use the same index in both $\bigcup A_i$ and $\bigcap B_i$ to show the implication, but what happens if it's not? What if $x\in A_j$ but $x\notin B_k$ for some $j\ne k$ instead? Well then clearly $x\in \bigcup A_j- \bigcap B_j$, but what about $A_j-B_j$ or $A_k-B_k$? Well that's not obvious, but if $A_j=B_j$ and $A_k=B_k$ then of course they become the empty set and $x$ is not a member.

So what we use as counter example is $A_1 = B_1 = \{1\}$ and $A_2=B_2=\emptyset$. Then $1\in \bigcup A_j - \bigcap B_j = \{1\}-\emptyset$, but $x\notin \bigcup(A_j-B_j) = (\{1\}-\{1\})\cup \{\emptyset-\emptyset\} = \emptyset$.